# How to visually setup a complex animation with css/js ui editor

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transition

I want to create complex animation but I'm trying to visually see and tweak it. It seems hard to figure this out by just testing several different numbers on keyframe animations? I'm looking to figure out how to see in an editor or tool animations that generate the code required like in this example: https://codepen.io/kilianso/pen/NaLzVW

```
/* STATE 2 */
.scroll__view[data-current="2"] {
  .rectangle-1 {
    background: #b3cc35;
    left: 34.398%;
    top: 60.665%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(27deg);
  }
  .rectangle-2 {
    background: #a4c339;
    left: 44.698%;
    top: 60.665%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(27deg);
  }
  .rectangle-3 {
    background: #92b93d;
    left: 54.898%;
    top: 60.665%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(27deg);
  }
  .rectangle-4 {
    background: #80b040;
    left: 65.298%;
    top: 60.665%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(27deg);
  }
  .rectangle-5 {
    background: #b3cc35;
    left: 34.398%;
    top: 60.665%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(27deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
```

I imagine the person who created an animation like this must have used some visual ui editor. Any idea or recommendations?

Comment: You can use your own code pen, just like the example you provided (you can also "fork" any pen and just start editing it). The pen allows you to save and see your changes visually right away, just like you're describing. If developing locally, [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is the editor of choice for most developers. Adding the ability to view live changes would depend on the local development setup for your project, but this is super common. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) is another really useful one. So, I suppose the answer is that there are many options :)

Comment: Thanks however none of those are really specific to generating css from using some kind of timeline ui editor. That still requires a lot of manual trial and error to get a super complex animation correct. I was hoping if there was a more clear tool or playground that lets you quickly do sequence animations.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. [Animista](https://animista.net/play/basic/scale-up) is one I’ve used. This won’t let you experiment with complex animations or a series of animations, but does provide a visual interface for quick editing and does generate the CSS. [Keyframes.app](https://keyframes.app/animate) looks like another one, although I can’t say I’ve found a playground or tool that does what you’re describing. Maybe those help though.

Comment: keyframes.app was pretty spot on. I ended up using also Theatre.JS which gave me a timeline editor. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Nice! Happy to hear it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theatre.js(https://www.theatrejs.com/) ultimately was the best in web app development solution with a low learning curve especially if you're using an idea like vscode